# How to control the data coming from mysql database in flutter?

Tags: mysql, list, flutter

I have this app which prints the list of data which I got from my test database - Users table `[{id: 2147483647, email: test@test.com, password: test12, username: User}]`
so I want to save the id, email, ..... in vars how ? also new to flutter :)
edit:
this is the function that I call in initState:

```
void fetchData() async {
    final response = await http.get('http://192.168.137.1/fetch_data.php');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        data = json.decode(response.body);
      });
      print(data);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `data` is `List<Map<String,dynamic>>` so for example to print all usernames you can do something like this:

```
data.forEach((item) { 
  print(item['username']);
});
```

Comment: But I have another question Can I search in the given data ?

Comment: As I want to do login.

Comment: @omardeveloper yes its not hard. just loop through the list and find the key on map